# how to tokenize multiple columns of a pandas dataframe for NLP

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, nltk

How to tokenize my data frame with numbers, which is having multiple columns of text data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the library you use for tokenizing, and apply it to multiple columns.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

def tokenize(text):
    return [tok.text for tok in nlp.tokenizer(text) if not tok.is_stop]

df['token'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: tokenize(x))
df['another_token'] = df['another_column_name'].apply(lambda y: tokenize(y))
```